# Read .DAT file created in C++ program in .NET C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to read a .DAT file that was created (as far as I know) in C++ program. This is a database file (it looks like). The curious thing is that if you drop the file into an EXCEL file its going to actually show a datatable!

[image: EXAMPLEEXCELDROP]

Here's what is inside the file if you open it in NOTEPAD:

[CONTENTSINSIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdAlH.png)

So this is a proof that is actually a database table?
The thing is that  I need to read this file and convert it into a datatable to work with in .NET C#

I would appreciate a lot your help :)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is the format of ..dat file is text delimited or binary file?

Comment: How does the file content look, if you open it in Notepad? The file could be in a CSV-format. If this is the case, it would display correctly in plain text.

Comment: Thanks for you response is just posted a picture in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NathanWay, you can open the file in excel, then **SAVE AS** CSV-Format.

After it, you can use the CSV file as data source of you C# project. You will need just a CSV parser to read and write the file.

Theres a simple parse example (explained in details) here on this link: [SIMPLE CSV PARSER](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp)

I've implemented once and it works like a charm.